# How to add correct labels for Seaborn Confusion Matrix

Tags: python, seaborn, confusion-matrix

I have plotted my data into a confusion matrix using `seaborn` but I ran into a problem. The problem is that it is only showing numbers from 0 to 11, on both axes, because I have 12 different labels.

My code looks as follows:

```
cf_matrix = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,10)) 
sns.heatmap(cf_matrix, linewidths=1, annot=True, ax=ax, fmt='g')
```

Here you can see my confusion matrix:

[image: Confusion matrix]

I am getting the confusion matrix as I should. The only problem is the names of the labels which are not shown. I have searched quite a while over the Internet and with no luck. Are there any parameters which can attach the labels or how can this be done?

Comment: You could try `sns.heatmap(....., xticklabels=['xlabel1', ...], yticklabels=['ylabel1', ...])`

Comment: Hi Johan, 
Thanks for your answer!
I have tried this and it is ok, but aren't there any automated methods which by itself can recognize that e.g. 0 is Label 1 etc.?

Comment: If the data come from a pandas dataframe, labels could be more automatic. Note that Python always starts counting from 0.  To get labels starting from 1, you could try ``..., xticklabels=range(1, myArray.shape[1]+1))`

Comment: Yea, the data comes from a dataframe, but it has been put through a neural network before plotting it in the confusion matrix.  I guess the easiest way to do is just to use the xticklabels and yticklabels and then manually writing the labels. 

Do you however know an easy way to figure out which label is which number?

Comment: Here you can see the precision and recall. The order the labels are in here, is that the same order as in the confusion matrix? i.e.0 in confusion matrix is 'New Product Action'?

https://imgur.com/IvZKCb2

Comment: Maybe the labels are in your `my_tags` variable?

Answer (score 1):

When you factorize your categories, you should have retained the levels, so you can use that in conjunction with `pd.crosstab` instead of `confusion_matrix` to plot. Using iris as example:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report, confusion_matrix

df = pd.read_csv("http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/iris/iris.data",
                 header=None,names=["s.wid","s.len","p.wid","p.len","species"])
X = df.iloc[:,:4]
y,levels = pd.factorize(df['species'])
```

At this part, you get the labels y in [0,..1,..2] and levels as the original labels to which 0,1,2 corresponds to:

```
Index(['Iris-setosa', 'Iris-versicolor', 'Iris-virginica'], dtype='object')
```

So we fit and do like what you have:

```
clf = RandomForestClassifier(max_depth=2, random_state=0)
clf.fit(X,y)
y_pred = clf.predict(X)
print(classification_report(y,y_pred,target_names=levels))
```

[image]

And a confusion matrix with 0,1,2:

```
cf_matrix = confusion_matrix(y, y_pred)
sns.heatmap(cf_matrix, linewidths=1, annot=True, fmt='g')
```

[image]

We go back and use the levels:

```
cf_matrix = pd.crosstab(levels[y],levels[y_pred])
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5,5))
sns.heatmap(cf_matrix, linewidths=1, annot=True, ax=ax, fmt='g')
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Labels are sorted alphabetically.
So, use numpy to DISTINCT the ture_label you will get an alphabetically sorted ndarray

```
cm_labels = np.unique(true_label)
cm_array = confusion_matrix(true_label, predict_label)
cm_array_df = pd.DataFrame(cm_array, index=cm_labels, columns=cm_labels)
sn.heatmap(cm_array_df, annot=True, annot_kws={"size": 12})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

# Predict the labels of the test set
y_pred = model.predict(X_test)

# Compute the confusion matrix
cm = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred, labels=[0, 1, 2])

# Define the labels and titles for the confusion matrix
classes = ['Negative', 'Neutral', 'Positive']
title = 'Confusion matrix for Logistic Regression model'

# Create a heatmap of the confusion matrix
sns.heatmap(cm, annot=True, cmap='Blues', fmt='g', xticklabels=classes, yticklabels=classes)

# Set the axis labels and title
plt.xlabel('Predicted')
plt.ylabel('Actual')
plt.title(title)

# Add legends for the heatmap
bottom, top = plt.ylim()
plt.ylim(bottom + 0.5, top - 0.5)
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
plt.yticks(rotation=0)
plt.show()
```